# Como pegar os menores indcies da lista, mas somente do indice 0 ao 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

```
z  = [-4, -1, 0, 0, 0]
F1 = [ 9,  1, 1, 0, 18]
F2 = [ 3,  1, 0, 1, 12]

#Pega a posição do menor valor das listas
n_min_z = min(z)
n_min_F1 = min(F1)
n_min_F2 = min(F2)

#Guarda a posição em uma variavel
posZ = z.index(n_min_z)
posF1 = F1.index(n_min_F1)
posF2 = F2.index(n_min_F2)

print(posZ)
print(posF1)
print(posF2)
```

o menor do F1 está no índice 3, mas eu queria o menor no índices 0 e 1, como faço e na lista F2 quero fazer a mesma coisa

Comment: Olá, você pode ordenar a lista para que o menor valor seja sempre no **indice 0**

Comment: e que a lista tem que estar nessa ordem é so posso pegar o menor valor dos índices 0 ou 1

Comment: entendi melhor agora, faça um fatiamento: `min(z[:2])` isso vai comparar apenas os dois primeiros indices. Depois você repete para os demais.

Comment: Obrigado, Funcionou!

Comment: @WilliamTeixeira caso queira copiar a parte que eu menciono você e postar como resposta, pode copiar, eu retiro da minha resposta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você só quer avaliar dois índices, não precisa complicar usando funções da linguagem, declarações ou fatiamento de sequências.

Para comparar dois valores, basta usar matemática básica. Com dois valores, um deles é o menor e o outro é o maior. Se forem iguais, não faz diferença.

Também não precisa repetir a lógica N vezes para N listas. Use um `for`.

```
z  = [-4, -1, 0, 0, 0]
F1 = [ 9,  1, 1, 0, 18]
F2 = [ 3,  1, 0, 1, 12]

for seq in [z, F1, F2]:
    print(0 if seq[0] <= seq[1] else 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma das maneiras de se fazer isso como o [@WilliamTeixeira](http://devfuria.com.br/python/sequencias-fatiamento/) disse, seria você [fatiar a `sequencia`](http://devfuria.com.br/python/sequencias-fatiamento/).

Algumas maneiras de você fazer isso:

```py
min(z[0:2])
min(z[:2])
min(z[-5:2]) #isso só ira funcionar se a lista tiver 5 elementos, por isso não é recomendavel
```

Fazendo isso o código ficara assim:

```py
z  = [-4, -1, 0, 0, 0]
F1 = [ 9,  1, 1, 0, 18]
F2 = [ 3,  1, 0, 1, 12]

#Pega a posição do menor valor das listas
n_min_z = min(z[:2])#ou alguma das outras opções
n_min_F1 = min(F1[:2])#ou alguma das outras opções
n_min_F2 = min(F2[:2])#ou alguma das outras 

#Guarda a posição em uma variavel
posZ = z.index(n_min_z)
posF1 = F1.index(n_min_F1)
posF2 = F2.index(n_min_F2)

print(posZ)
print(posF1)
print(posF2)
```

Mas uma outra maneira de você conseguir fazer isso é com um `if`, só que código ficara maior:

```py
z  = [-4, -1, 0, 0, 0]
F1 = [ 9,  1, 1, 0, 18]
F2 = [ 3,  1, 0, 1, 12]

#Pega a posição do menor valor das listas

if z[0] > z[1]:
    n_min_z = z[0]
else:
    n_min_z = z[1]
if F1[0] > F1[1]:
    n_min_F1 = F1[0]
else:
    n_min_F1 = F1[1]
if F2[0] > F2[1]:
    n_min_F2 = F2[0]
else:
    n_min_F2 = F2[1]


#Guarda a posição em uma variavel
posZ = z.index(n_min_z)
posF1 = F1.index(n_min_F1)
posF2 = F2.index(n_min_F2)

print(posZ)
print(posF1)
print(posF2)
```

Comment: Acho que seria legal você alterar de "fatiar string" pra "fatiar sequência" para corresponder melhor com a realidade ([glossário](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-slice)).

Comment: Pronto, editei, muito interessante esse link.